# "run: not found" Error When Deploying MERN App to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I am trying to deploy my MERN web application to Heroku, but I have been getting this error:

```
remote: sh: 1: run: not found
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote: npm ERR! file sh
remote: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! reach-app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run build`
remote: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the reach-app@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

In terms of my structure, I have two directories in my root directory, called **client** and **backend**. Both of these directories each have their own package.json. I also initlialised git and another npm in the root directory. So, could it possibly be a problem with my file structure?

It doesn't seem like there are any other similar questions out there, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:
This is my package.json in my root directory:

```
{
  "name": "reach-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Initialised npm for the root directory.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server/index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install && npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "Phillip La",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a typo in your script; it should be `npm install && npm run build` instead.

Comment: Can you add package.json in your question code?

Comment: Wow, thank you. I was able to deploy my app, but my heroku page now says "Application Error".